# How can I use RapidMiner to detect very weak associations in a large dataset?

Tags: associations, design-patterns, rapidminer

I have a huge dataset of book titles and their authors and would like to find which authors are more likely to work with each other! I'm trying to figure it out by the association rules and fp-growth modules in rapidminer but it's not working! I think because the word vector is very large and the cooperation between the scientists would not be a big number in comparison with the whole matrix!

Could you please tell me how can I solve this problem or, if there is a similar free software that I can use for this purpose.

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is there a error message? How does your process look like?